# Facebook authorization in my Android app

Tags: android, facebook

How can I check if a user has account on an Android device, not to check this in my program?
How can I check the authenticity if the device is software Facebook for Android?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your english is a bit shakey but what i think you mean is:

How can I (being you the question giver) check if a Facebook account is already on an driod device instead of authentication through your application.

That may require some work with the facebook api due to permissions you ask from the user.

This however http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/package-summary.html May help you atleast determine the account and perhaps use it for auto login so its just the Allow / Denny stage being handled within your app rather than requiring them to log in

Answer (score 2):

using the Facebook sdk for android, you don't have to care if the user has the facebook or not. If he/she does, the sdk will use it authenticate. If she/he doesn't a webview will appear to authenticate the user.

You won't have access to user credentials easily (also you can still, but this is not fair for the user) and that's fine. All you are concerned about is to get the return of the method authorize (the onComplete method of you dialog listener will be called). And that's it. Later on, you can be sure the user is authenticated and you can start using the facebook api.